# Crystal Report unable to display

Tags: apache, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010 asp.net and crystal report ver.13 for my project, everything work fine until i publish my project to Apache. Crystal report was not display although the other page works fine. Is it possible to run crystal report on APACHE which is configured using mod_aspdotnet

Help and advise is needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the runtimes on your apache server?

Comment: i am a new comer trying to learn things.. i've search through web but still unable to get it. How do i exactly install the runtime on apache server?

Comment: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083 you want the 32bit or 64bit redist

Comment: Downloading the 32 bit Redist Installation. What should be done next?